# Unable to see few polygon labels

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am working on polygon shapefile and I want to display all the labels in the map. But, I am unable to see the labels of few polygons. I checked my geometry, I almost tried every single permutation and combination mentioned in Layer->Labeling.

Please tell me how to resolve this problem?

[image: Please see in the image id's of few polygons are not displayed]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @TejasG! Did you check if those polygons without labels actually have an _attribute value_ for QGIS to label?